# Can [asp.net-identity-2] be merged into [asp.net-identity]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

Seems to me these tags are serving the same purpose and many people are just double tagging questions with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very common for tags to have both versioned and unversioned variants.

[asp.net-identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-identity) appears to be for the common version, including version 1 and 2.

[asp.net-identity-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-identity-2) appears to be for issues specific to version 2.

I don't see a great reason to make [asp.net-identity-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-identity-2) a synonym of [asp.net-identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-identity).

Comment: Yes you are right, I don't know what I was thinking. I'm going to clean up this tag to have some meaningful information for its use.